# Google Analytics - Change old data using import feature for custom dimension used in a view filter

Tags: google-analytics

We have a custom dimension for "Product Category Code" and a views that are based on filtering different values for Product Category Code. If the code changes for some reason , we are thinking of using the data import feature to update the custom dimension retroactively. During the test , we notice that the custom dimension values are being refreshed after using Query time processing . However it does not sounds like we are able to apply the change in views retroactively though. Is there any way the change in value can be applied in view filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google analytics records the data you send to it and processes that. Once the data has been sent it is set in stone there is no way to change it.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently there is no way to dynamically or retroactively change the filters.